# Using an inductor and AC source to rise the current of an appliance

Tags: circuit-analysis

> An Arc lamp requires a direct current of 10A and 80V to function. If it is connected to a 220V,50 Hz Ac supply, the series inductor needed for it to work is close to:

To solve this question, we first compute the resistance of the inductor by Ohms law, then write the equation with impedance:

$$ 220= (10A) \sqrt{R^2 + (2\pi fL)^2}$$

i.e: find and L such that the current is 10A

About this , I have two main questions:

1. Firstly, we no longer give it 80V, so how is it only neccesary condition that appliance receives correct current for it to work properly?
2. In the AC circuit, the voltage and current is always oscillating as some sinusoid, so wouldn't this oscillation damage the device?

Comment: You give the circuit 220V; this is divided between L and R such that 10A leaves 80V across R.

Comment: Hmm how do you know for sure that's exactly how it's divided @BrianDrummond

Comment: By choosing L...

Comment: L was choosen on the condition that 10A goes through the component not on that the R should have 80V and the rest goes on it.. I can't see why both ideas are equivalent

Comment: When 10A dc current causes  80V across R so why shouldn't 10A rms current causes 80V rmsacross R using Ohm's law?

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. We can infer that from applying the Ohm's law on the resistor in AC circuit. Thank you @user215805

Comment: What's an AC battery?

Comment: AC source @Hearth fixed that